# how do an infinite loop in javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, infinite-loop

Im trying to do an infinite loop using while between 0 to 100 and 100 to 0, but the browser crashes. There is a way to clear the browser memory? This is my code:

```
var a = 0;
var flag = true;

while (true) {

    if (a < 100 && flag == true) {

        a++;

    } else {

        a = 0;
        flag = false;

        if (a < 0) {
            flag = true;
        }

    }

    console.log(a);

}
```

Comment: Well, you can always expect a browser crash with an infinite loop

Comment: With respect, that code doesn't make a lot of sense. You have a flag you never use, a variable that goes from 0 to 99 and then 0 to 99 and then 0 to 99, and a condition (`if (a < 0)`) that will never be met.

Comment: Didn't you want to use `flag` as condtion for `while` loop?
Like `while (flag) {(...)}`? Then loop will actually exit at some point and should not crash anything.

Comment: **If** your goal is to have a go from 0 to 100 and then back to 0, you need to keep track of which direction you're going, e.g.: `var a = 0, step = 1; do { console.log(a); a += step; if (a == 100) { step = -1; } } while (a >= 0);` That won't be infinite, won't crash the browser, and does take `a` on the desired journey.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish with an infinite loop? Maybe we can suggest something that will not crash the browser.

Comment: what is the use of flag.

Comment: I want going from 0 to 100 and then back to 0 in an infinite loop. sorry about var flag, was my mistake

Comment: *"I want going from 0 to 100 and then back to 0"* But why? What are you doing inside the loop? While the loop is running (forever) no other code can run, so doing that is pointless. You probably want something with `setTimeout` but unless you are explaining the problem you are trying to solve with this loop we cannot really help you.

Comment: this smells like a homework assignment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An infinite while loop will block the main thread wich is equivalent to a crash.
You could use a selfcalling function ( wich leaves the main thread doing some other stuff inbetween):

```
(function main(counter){
    console.log(counter);
    setTimeout(main,0,counter+1);
})(0);
```

You can put a loop that goes from 0 to 100, and one that goes from 100 to 0 into it, without blocking the browser too much:

```
(function main(){
    for(var counter=0;counter<100;counter++){
       console.log(counter);
    }
   console.log(100);
    while(counter){
       console.log(--counter);
    }
    setTimeout(main,0);
})();
```

http://jsbin.com/vusibanuki/edit?console

Further research: *JS IIFEs* , *function expression*, *non-blocking trough setTimeout* ...

Answer (score -2):

> There is a way to clear the browser memory?

Yes. Virtually all browsers have a little icon somewhere that looks very similar to this: [image]

This is called the "refresh". If you use this it will "clear the browser memory".

Answer (score -4):

You just need an infinite loop? If so just do

```
for(var i = 0; i < 1;){
  console.log('infinite');
};
```

if you need with a while

```
var = 0;
while(var < 1){
  console.log('looOOoOOoOoOp');
};
```

Comment: I also always need an infinite loop for the customers websites.

Comment: @FelixKling Nothing as far as I can tell. It's simple. It's straight forward. It's clean and obvious what it does and what the author's intentions are. Best damn infinite loop I've seen in a long minute.

Comment: @FelixKling there's nothing, but why declare 2 variables to use in a loop? There's nothing wrong with `while(true)`, it's just a different aproach.