# how to make a loop wait code execution for x period in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I want to execute a function inside a never ending loop after every 5 seconds.

I tried a bunch of things but they failed me, I.e below:

**#1:**

```
while(1){ setTimeout(function(){ executeThis(); },3000); console.lop("This is to text that loop has stopped till executeThis function have been finished");}
```

Although `executeThis()` would be called after 3 seconds, but in the mean time, the loops keep executing `console.log()` dozens of thousands times, which make the browser crash.

**#2:**

```
setTimeout(function(){ while(1){executeThis();} },3000);
```

This one just keep calling `executeThis()` and crash browser again.

Is there a better way to call my function after x seconds and make the loop stop executing till the function is finished?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do an infinite loop in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43922400/how-do-an-infinite-loop-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

setInterval will do the job

```
//sends hello every half sec.
setInterval(function(){console.log('hello');}, 500);
```

Comment: well no need for while(), thank you :)